# Problem with TIME variable values in SPSS

Tags: variables, time, spss

I need your suggestions how i can convert my time variable (Time_A, string format) into numeric format.
The values are entered as follows: **hmm** or **hhmm**.

Please give suggestions, how to solve this problem.
Regards.

When i use time and date function in SPSS, hhmm values convert good, however nothing happens with hmm values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is SPSS expects the first two characters to represent hours, and when the hour is less then 10 there is only one charachter. The solution is to add the missing character, which in these cases should be "0". So do the following before running the date-time transformations:

```
compute Time_A=char.lpad(Time_A, 4, "0").
```

This will turn your 3 digit strings into 4 digit strings that begin with "0".

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked very nice. I have however another problem now with same variable.

Value 9999 - means that the hh and mm are missing, so it should be missing value.
Value hh99, means that i know hour but not minutes. 

when u use the code you have provided, it codes hh99 values as missing. I need however them to be coded as hh00. 

How can achieve this?

Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: I can help with that too but filrst please post this problem as a new question so we can keep the present post and the answer focused on a single clear problem.

Comment: Also see my edit of the answer above, changed `lpad` to `char.lpad` which is more updated

Comment: I have done so, thank you for suggestion.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75557054/missing-values-on-time-variable-spss

Answer (score 1):

@eli-k has answered with a good explanation.

Another solution would be:

```
compute Time_A_num = NUMBER(RIGHT("0" + Time_A, 4), F4).
```

as it achieves the same result in fewer steps. It also creates a new variable, which avoids modifying the original data and allows for comparison with the original variable if necessary.

Comment: You're right this could be shorter but note that the OP needs a transformation into a time variable and not into a number. Also note that `"text1"+"text1"` won't work in SPSS syntax - you'd need `concat("text1","text2")` instead.