# Missing values on time variable, SPSS

Tags: time, encoding, missing-data, spss

I have problem with time variable (coded as hmm or hhmm) what is recorded as string. I need help with following:
Value 9999 has to be coded as missing, NA.
Value h99 or hh99, needs to be coded as h00 or hh00

How can achieve this? Thank you very much for the answer.

Tried to change the values manually.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace "99" with "00", but that would cause "9999" to become "0000" which could be interpreted as a legitimate hour. So, I suggest two separate steps - take care of "9999" first and then replace "99":

```
recode YourTimeValue("9999"="").
compute YourTimeValue=replace(YourTimeValue, "999","900").
compute YourTimeValue=replace(YourTimeValue, "99","00").
exe.
```

Now you can transform the text into a time variable.

Comment: Thank you. The code 'compute YourTimeValue=replace(YourTimeValue, "99","00")."
Is there risk that if the value is 999 (hmm) will be replaced to 009 instead of 900?

Comment: i have tried the code and it actually replaced 999 to 009. it should be 900.

What i have done now is 
compute YourTimeValue=replace(YourTimeValue, "009","900").

Comment: Ach you're absolutely right, I didn't take "999" or "1999" into account... See my corrected code, with an additional step.